# Start Windows Program from Linux in a virtual machine.

Tags: java, linux, windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to start a Windows program on virtual machine from Linux.
Are there opportunities to start a program directly on VM from the outside.
I tried WINE to emulate this program, but it does not work.

One idea I have, to implement WebService on the virtual machine and call this from Linux. 
The web service would then call the program under Windows and play back the result.

Has anyone experience or better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps install freeSSHd on the Windows box, generate some public/private keys between your two servers, connect through to Windows and use use the cmd runas command to start your program/service.

Comment: Is it possible to use public/private keys on not a windows server?